# ¿Como convertir un archivo .exe a un array de bytes?

Tags: java

¿De que forma puedo convertir un archivo con extensión .exe a un array de bytes utilizando java? 
He probado con el siguiente código, pero solo funciona para archivos de texto.

```
File soft = jcf.getSelectedFile();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(soft);
archivoBytes = new byte[(int) soft.length()];
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
int leidos;

while ((leidos = bis.read(b)) > 0) {
      bis.read(archivoBytes, 0, leidos);
}
bis.close();
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Existen algún otro método para la conversión?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso en específico, no se requiere una instancia de `BufferedInputStream` ni tampoco el ciclo `while`, sino simplemente:

```
File soft = new File("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
byte[] archivoBytes = new byte[(int) soft.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(soft);
fis.read(archivoBytes);
fis.close();
```

Comment: Funciono correctamente. Gracias

Comment: Solo funciona para archivos pequeños. Para archivos grandes ya no fucniona.

Comment: Posiblemente necesites incrementar la memoria a Java. ¿Qué tan grande es el archivo que deseas leer? -- Sólo por curiosidad, ¿qué planeas hacer con el arreglo de bytes?

Comment: He probado con archivos de 200 MB. Guardarlo en una base de datos. Estoy utilizando hibernate para ello. Con archivos pequeños si funciona.

Comment: Imagino que te aparece el error de `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: En java no manda error alguno. Supongo que es la forma de guardar con hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sería Mediante el método [readAllBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) de la clase `File`

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    Path archivo= Paths.get("urldelexe");
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(archivo);
     /* Impresión de los Bytes Obtenidos*/
    for (byte e : data) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

 /* Una Sola Línea */
 byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(new File("urldelexe").toPath());
```